# Automatically collapsing in Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 like in TwitterBootstrap 3.3.0

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My site is http://get2gethersports.com

I created a custom mail chimp subscription form using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 based off of a 3.3.0 one I did.

The basic core part of the code is below:

```
<div style="color:black;text-align:center;"><form class="form-inline" action="//get2gethersports.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=7c0d513e0a7edb9e73598c3d8&amp;id=dac19d65a1" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="_blank" novalidate="">
<h2>Join our mailing list!</h2>
<p style="font-size:15px;">Sign up with your email address to receive the latest news and updates from get2gether|sports</p>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email" name="EMAIL">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="First Name" name="FNAME">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="Last Name" name="LNAME">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Subscribe</button>
<p style="font-size:12px;">We respect your privacy.</p>
</form></div>
```

The problem is in 3.3.0 it worked fabulously collapsing when the screen got below 768px.
in 2.3.2 I don't see how to do that anywhere in the documentation. So sometimes the rows stack next to each other rather then below. Best seen on Iphone 6.

Is there anyway to make them auto collapse below 768px like in 3.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it using

```
@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 980px) {
#subform {
    width:320px!important;
    margin:0px auto!important;
}
}
```